# How do I get my script to cycle through all variable combinations, then have it stop and try the next combination if a condition isnt fulfilled?

Tags: r, loops, return, combinations

I have a list of incomplete 121 matrices (land.vbmx) that I can't evaluate all at once. So I need to evaluate every combination of the 31 variables (rows in matrices.

So far as I've been writing the analyses part of my script, I have been manually choosing my variables by removing them form a list of variables to remove and running my script only once.

```
#Choose variables under study and delete the variables (rows) to be excluded
land.vbmx <- lapply(land.121mx, `[`, -c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31),)

#Now delete all harpoon heads with missing data
land.vb <- Filter(Negate(anyNA), land.vbmx)

#Remaining matrices = sample size
ml <- length(land.vb)

#If ml is smaller than 20, return to variable selection
if(ml < 20) {
  #return to variable selection
}
```

Now that its time to run my script across all variables I find myself stumped as to how to try it out.

What I'm trying to have it do is:

1. Spit out one combination of my 31 variables (ie 1,2,4) without repeating them in different orders
2. Proceed to remove all other rows
3. Remove all the matrices that have NA within the remaining rows
4. Calculate the remaining matrix sample size
5. If the sample size is below 20, have it stop and return to the variable selection line and choose the next combination of variables
6. OR If sample is 20 and above, go through whole script and return to variable selection when complete and choose the next combination of variables

I have steps 2,3,4 down, step 5 partially down, but 1 escapes me. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `combn` function to get distinct subsets of values. `x` is the vector to draw from, and `m` is the size of subsets.

```
triplets <- combn(x = 1:31, m = 3)
triplets[, 1:5]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    2    2    2    2
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7
```

`combn` also works with character vectors, if you have row names.
Next, you loop over the columns and use their indices.

```
for (ii in seq_len(ncol(triplets))) {
  keep_rows <- triplets[, ii]
  submatrices <- lapply(land.121mx, `[`, keep_rows, )
  # Steps 3 through 5...
}
```

Comment: Looks awesome, is it possible to get the combinations to include 3:31 variables (ie more than 3?)

Comment: You could do `lapply(3:31, combn, x = 1:31)`, then loop over that.  Note that there are 300,540,195 combinations of 15 elements from 31, so it might take a while.

Comment: Indeed! Its using up 23GB of ram. I'll report on how it goes. Otherwise is there way to do it iteratively? Where it generates the combination to be used as it goes?

Comment: Yikes! Got the error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 13.8 Gb.

Comment: There's probably a way to do it by building up subsets in a combination of `while` and `for` loops so you only have one subset at a time, but I can't seem to put an example together right now.